# What is nobody@localhost in Google calendar app

Tags: android-versions, google-calendar, android-x86

I seen something strange option in my Google calendar app in my realme mobile.

There is account with name "NOBODY@LOCALHOST" and with the check box option "nobody@localhost"

I didn't seen before in my past mobile

Any solution appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mostly appears in Oppo/Realme phones or maybe all phones from China.

Anyway,to remove it,install on your phone iCal from Google Play Store.
Open the app, use it to look at the calendars on your phones, choose nobody@localhost and delete it using iCal. Job done.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Hi, I've got a similar issue. There is no "iCal" app on the Google Play Store that I can see, could you clarify which app you're referring to? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find iCal in the play store, but you can also use CalendarSync trial to remove the nobody@localhost calendar from your device.